# How to have two different text boxes determine if numbers are entered, when only letters are allowed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Only letters are allowed to be entered in the "txtfirstname" and "txtlastname." Both events are handled under one exception (per professor) I don't know what statement to use for both events to be handled separately. Image of it working does not have (txtFirstName OrElse txtLastName, "Can only be letters"). I can get the first name to work correctly, but I cannot get both first and last name to work at the same time.

[image: Only working for First name]

```
 Private Sub OnlyLetter_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtFirstName.KeyPress, txtLastName.KeyPress
        'prevents numbers from being entered into First name or Last name textbox
        If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then Exit Sub
        If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = True
            errorProvider.SetError(txtFirstName OrElse txtLastName, "Can only be letters")
        Else
            errorProvider.SetError(txtFirstName, String.Empty)
        End If
```

Comment: You don't post links to code at SO.  You post code and ensure that it is formatted correctly so that we can read it easily.  That said, if you want a single method to handle events for multiple objects then you simply edit the `Handles` clause to include a comma-delimited list of the events to handle. Inside the method, you can access the object that raised the event via the `sender` parameter, Alternatively, have individual event handlers that then call a common method that does all the work.

Comment: Looking at your code you are hardcoding your textboxes into a common handler, you already know the textbox that caused the error since it is the sender. Cast it to textbox and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
 Private Sub OnlyLetter_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtFirstName.KeyPress, txtLastName.KeyPress
    If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then Exit Sub
    If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
        errorProvider.SetError(DirectCast(sender, Textbox) ,"Can only be letters")
    Else
        errorProvider.SetError(DirectCast(sender, Textbox) , String.Empty)
    End If
 End Sub
```